# What is the value of the following summation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

> Compute 
>   $$\displaystyle\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{9^n(2n+2)}$$

I am given the fact that 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2}
$$
but I still don't have any clue how to calculate the sum for the first series. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about using $x=1/3$?

Comment: @leo Consider up-voting and accepting answer if it helps! (by clicking on $\checkmark$)

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ I like those special $\LaTeX$ symbols :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{9^n(2n+2)} = - 9\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{(\frac{1}{3})^{2n+2}}{2n+2}$